# This is an exercise in CLRS 4th Edition. I am not sure how to solve this question, and I am not even sure how I would use equation 3.14

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Use equation (3.14) or other means to show that $(n+o(n))^{k}=\Theta\left(n^{k}\right)$ for any real constant $k$. Conclude that $\lceil n\rceil^{k}=\Theta\left(n^{k}\right)$ and $\lfloor n\rfloor^{k}=\Theta\left(n^{k}\right)$.

Where equation (3.14) is:

$1+x \leq e^{x}$

Comment: Hint: $n+o(n)=n(1+o(1))$.

Comment: We're not particularly looking for posts that consist solely of an exercise-style task.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n) \in o(n)$ and consider sufficiently large values of $n$.
There is some constant $c$ s.t. $f(n) \le cn$. Defining $c' = (1+c)^k$ (notice that $c'$ is a constant):
$$
n^k \le (n+ f(n))^k \le (n(1+c))^k = n^k (1+c)^k = c' n^k
$$

Then you just need to observe that:
$$
n^k \le \lceil n \rceil^k \le (n+1)^k = O(n^k)
$$
and (since $k$ is a constant):
$$
n^k \ge\lfloor n \rfloor^k \ge \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^k = \frac{n^k}{2^k} = \Omega(n^k)
$$

Comment: Thank you, good answer